# Why is the same virtual machine used when trying to setup a new instance?

Tags: virtual-machine, vagrant, virtualbox

I copied an existing vagrant config in order to ease the setup. When I run `vagrant up`, I had expected for a new machine to be setup. Yet instead, it says it starts the `default` machine which is exactly the same as the vm for my existing project.

I do not want to run `vagrant destroy` as I do not want to provision both projects again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copying the existing vagrant directory also copied the hidden directory `.vagrant`. There, the references to the created virtual box are stored. Vagrant hence *thought* it already had set up the machine already and that it was the same one as from the existing project.

Deleting this folder in the new project deletes the reference, so the existing virtual box machines will be kept, and running `vagrant up` will then provision a new machine and create its own virtual box.